# extern keyword with pointers couldn't pass correct values

Tags: c

I am using extern to pass values between two C files:

```
//For the first case as follows: I was not able to print out correct values. 
//Everything print out is 0. 
//In file1.c,
int * element_list;

void set_element()
{
    ......
    element_list = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         element_list[i] = i;
    }
    ......
}



//In file2.c,

extern int * element_list;

void print_element()
{
    ......
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       printf("%d", element_list[i]);
    }
    ....
}
```

If I initialize element_list to array like this, I am able to print out correct values.

```
// After changing the following two lines in two files,
// I was able to print out correct values 
//In file1.c, change to
int element_list[MAX_NUM_ELEMENTS];

//In file2.c, change to 
extern int element_list[MAX_NUM_ELEMENTS];
```

I don't understand why using malloc caused this issue. I didn't reset elements to 0 before printing them out. In my program, to get correct results, I only replaced malloc with array, everything else in the program is exactly the same.

Comment: In the pointer case, do the two functions have the same idea of what the value of `num_elements` is?  Does it change between calls to these functions?

Comment: `printf( "%p %d\n", element_list, num_elements );` Place that printf before the `for` loop in both files and see if you get the same values.

Comment: You have `extern int * element_list;` but apparently not `extern int num_elements;`

Comment: Silly question, but did you call `set_element()` before calling `print_element()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* first file aaa.c */
extern void print_val();

int* element_list;
int num_elements = 10;
int main() {
    int i;
    element_list = malloc(num_elements * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
        element_list[i] = i;
    }
    print_val();
    return 0;
}
```

Please notice that I am calling the print_val() function in my main function, to ensure that I am calling the external function found in file bbb.c

```
/* Second file bbb.c */
extern int *element_list;

void print_val()
{
    int j;

    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        printf("val = %d\n", element_list[j]);
    }
}
```

To compile it on a Linux machine, use:

```
gcc aaa.c bbb.c -o output
```

Then run it, I got the following:

```
ccampes@campes tmp $ ./output 
val = 0
val = 1
val = 2
val = 3
val = 4
val = 5
val = 6
val = 7
val = 8
val = 9
```

I think the way you were compiling it could be the error.
I hope this can solve your question.